# How to parse contact form 7 fields and attributes

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am working on a  custom form builder plugin, and I want to develop a feature that will allow users to convert a CF7 form into my custom form. Any hints on how to achieve that would be really appreciated. My plugin is basically a block in Gutenberg that has multiple form fields as child blocks.

For example, I somehow want this contact form 7 code.

```
<label> Your Name (required)
[text* your-name] </label>

<label> Your Email (required)
[email* your-email] </label>

<label> Subject
[text your-subject] </label>

<label> Your Message
[textarea your-message] </label>
<label>

Hey !
[select menu-805 "Hello" "World"]
</label>


[submit "Send"]
```

To be converted in my form block in Gutenberg with shortcode